# Navigate the page

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-layout

I am new to Flutter. I know how to navigate from a page to another page, but the problem is, my navigation does not work. In my short experience, I realized that you cannot navigate from the stateless to the stateful widget or the opposite one.

I will share my code below. So could you please tell me what kind of mistake I am making?

Thank you. :)

**Actually I was planning to remove the button because this page could be the intro page like it could show the image and text I want and after 3 seconds it could go to the MainApp() page. Maybe if you have any idea how to do it. I would like to hear that too.:)**

```
void main() {
  runApp(Intro());
}

class Intro extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _IntroState createState() => _IntroState();
}

class _IntroState extends State<Intro> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellow.shade300,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: (Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/dinoapp2.png',
                    height: 200.0,
                    width: 200.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Big Title',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Russo One Regular',
                        fontSize: 30.0,
                        color: Colors.blueAccent),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(120.0, 20, 120, 100),
                child: RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainApp()),
                    );
                  },
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  textColor: Colors.black,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Text(
                    "Start",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainAppState createState() => _MainAppState();
}

class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: Text('This page I want to go after I press Start button'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
void main() {
      runApp(MaterialApp(
        home: Intro(),
      ));
    }
    
    class Intro extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _IntroState createState() => _IntroState();
    }
    
    class _IntroState extends State<Intro> {
      @override
      void initState() {
        Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
          Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainApp());
    
          Navigator.push(context, route);
        });
        super.initState();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.yellow.shade300,
          body: SafeArea(
            child: (Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/dinoapp2.png',
                      height: 200.0,
                      width: 200.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Big Title',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Russo One Regular',
                          fontSize: 30.0,
                          color: Colors.blueAccent),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                )
              ],
            )),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MainApp extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MainAppState createState() => _MainAppState();
    }
    
    class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Center(
              child: Text('This page I want to go after I press Start button'),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome brother, try to use matrialApp widget once

Answer (score 0):

**Just Add this function in your intro class**

```
   @override
   void initState() {
   super.initState();
   Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
   Navigator.push( context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>      
   MainApp()),
   );  }); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: I just upload the image]

I don't know why but I copied your code into Intro class. It didn't work. :(

Comment: He use material app two times also some other mistake , check my code